# Save Image which is inside a content control

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol

I'm having a content control which have a image inside when im trying to save that image im getting a black image. What am i missing.

```
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)content1.ActualWidth, (int)content1.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            rtb.Render(content1);

            PngBitmapEncoder pnge = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            pnge.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
            Stream stream = File.Create(DriveName + ":/OpenCV/Images/UI/LeftEdge.png");
            pnge.Save(stream);
            stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your ContentControl hasn't been layouted when you try to render it.

Try to call UpdateLayout() on it.

If that doesn't do the trick try calling first Measure(), than Arrange() - also before rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this :

```
if (control.Type == WdContentControlType.wdContentControlPicture)
{
    if (control.Range.InlineShapes.Count != 0)
    {
        // Clear previous shapes
        foreach (InlineShape shape in control.Range.InlineShapes)
        {
            if (shape.Type == WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
            {
                shape.Delete();
            }
         }

         // Add new shape
         InlineShape img = control.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture (valueToSet, false, true);
         img.Width = 90;
         img.Height = 90;
    }
}
```